# how to retrieve parent's value based on child

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve the user's key based on the child's email, which is student@memail.com in this case. I have tried many ways but could not get a way to retrieve the key of the record. I want to retrieve the value KKTxEMxrAYVSdtr0K1NH , below is the snapshot of the database

[image: database]

Currently, `if((childSnap.val().role) == "student") {` returns me student and snap.key() returns me "User". How do I retrieve KTxEMxrAYVSdtr0K1NH ?

Answer (score 1):

What method are you using to retrieve the node? If you are using on "child_added" then you can use: **childSnap.key**

If you are using on "value" then your references is the keys in the response object. So you can use:

```
for (var key in childSnap.val()) {
console.log(key)
}
```

or

```
childSnap.forEach(...)
```

Here is an example to clearify (check the console):
https://jsfiddle.net/qrLvbok4/1/

There is a difference between value and child_added, check the list for child events section: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data

Answer (score 1):

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('Users');
ref.on('child_added', function(snap) {
    // You can retrieve the parent key by calling snap.key
    console.log(snap.key);
});
```

UPDATE (Get parent key by email):

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('Users').orderByChild('email').startAt('student@memail.com').endAt('student@memail.com');
ref.once('value', function(snap) {
    console.log(Object.keys(snap.val())[0]);
});
```

Comment: hi, thank you for replying. It works, but currently it logs all of the keys, but I only want a particular key which is the one 'KTxEMxrAYVSdtr0K1NH'. Any idea how do i retrieve this particular one considering I can retrieve the email ?'

Comment: @purplewind i've updated my answer, see "Get parent key by email".